# A way to create a hoverIntent type delay effect with CSS3?

Tags: css, events, delay, hoverintent

So when I quickly move my mouse over an object, it wont fire it's animation, not until the user hold their mouse over that object for a specified number of ms. I don't believe this can be done with just CSS3, but maybe I'm wrong?

This effect is for if I have something like a bunch of links, and each link launched a little tooltip bubble, if the user moves their mouse across the screen to click on something, we don't want all of those tooltip bubbles to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, this would be great! But it's not possible since you can't hold an animation with CSS3. Since you've hovered an element, all animations binded to it will be fired :S

Why don't you suggest it as a [Chrome Feature](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/static.py?hl=pt-BR&page=suggestions.cs)?